# Django-CMS, how to resolve a named apphook URL from a management command?

Tags: django-cms, django-manage.py

I've got a management command which sends email. In this email, I'd like to include a URL to a signup form, which is an apphook module in the CMS.

How can I resolve the URL to that path?

From the management command, I only see the plain URLconf, without the changes made by Django-CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem. It turns out that the pages may not appear in the URLconf (or urlpatterns), but the `reverse()` will work nevertheless.

The pagename does have to be fixed with the language code. For example:

```
reverse('nl:my-profile')
```

And the `cms.appresolvers` module will do it's work to find the page.